# Fedora/ Gnome: Disable sleep when undocking

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, power-management, sleep

**Ask**: I am looking for a way to stop my Fedora 32 notebook from going to sleep when I remove the external monitor (lid is always closed, it is always plugged in)

**Use case**: I have a WFH setup where I have one monitor, one Fedora 32 installed on Dell, and a work computer. Every (work-)morning, I plug in the HDMI from my personal to my work computer, and every evening, I plug it back into the personal Fedora machine. When I do that, **I notice that it wakes up from sleep.**

I also use it as alarm, and so on days I do not use it in the evening (And hence never switch the HDMI), it does not play the alarm in the morning. (No, I did not oversleep it, on at least one occasion I was up before the time)

**Things I've tried**:

1. Note that I'm not using the laptop screen at all, only the external monitor. So, the `LidSwitch` settings should not matter since the *Lid* is never *Switching*.

   Even so, I've edited the `etc/systemd/logind.conf` file, so the relevant part looks like this:

```
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=lock
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

Also, to take this further, I've edited the `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` file so that it now contains `IgnoreLid=true`

2. I've looked around on the internet, but people do not seem to be facing this issue that much. Most of the Stack overflow questions I came across pivoted on changing the lid setting.

I am more interested to know if there is a way to stop the computer from going to sleep when the lid is always down, but an external monitor is added/removed short of writing my own script to listen in on `\dev` or to make the alarm wake up the computer first